# Armazenar valores de um data set em variaveis ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, dataset

Estou com problemas para conseguir armazenar o retorno de um select em variaveis , estou usando um data set para criar uma tabela com o resultado do select , esse select ira me devolver alguns registros e da formar que estou fazendo so consigo pegar o primeiro valor , ja pesquisei como fazer lista e percorrer usando for each mais não estou conseguindo oir em pratica aqui vai um pedaço do codigo

```
DataSet dtteste = conexao.getDataSet("SELECT ID_FUNCIONARIO FROM VW_APONTAMENTO_HORAS WHERE ID_PROJETO="+idProjeto+"GROUP BY ID_FUNCIONARIO");
var count = dtteste.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
foreach(DataRow teste in dtteste.Tables[0].Rows )
{

   var retorno = dtteste.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString();
   var retorno1 = dtteste.Tables[0].Rows[2].ToString();
   var retorno3 = dtteste.Tables[0].Rows[4].ToString();
}
```

Desta forma ele n apresenta nada de resultado, acho que preciso converter de SQL pra `int` ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Não seria a variavel `teste`dentro do `foreach`?

Comment: voce estava certo mesmo eu estava confundido

Comment: adicionei      var retorno4 = teste[0].ToString(); e apareceu o primeiro valor , mais o segundo valor eu n consigo acessar , se eu mudo o "[1]", ele vaipra coluna e n consigo colocar      var retorno4 = teste[0].rows[1]ToString();  alguma sugestão .... mais de qualquer forma ja agradeço a primeira ajuda

Comment: na sua SQL não tem o segundo campo! só tem ID_Funcionario!

Comment: Apenas recomendando uma leitura: [Porque evitar DataTable e DataSet](http://thiagolunardi.net/2015/03/porque-evitar-datatable-e-dataset/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está percorrendo cada linha do DataTable dentro do foreach, sendo necessário apenas informar a coluna. Você também não pode ter retorno, retorno1 e retorno2 para pegar os resultados. Imagine que você terá 50 linhas, vai declarar 50 variáveis ? 
Utilize uma lista para armazenar cada valor que tiver retornado.

A utilização do DataSet / DataTable / DataRow é a seguinte:

`DataSet.Tables[t]` onde t é o nome ou índice da tabela.

`DataSet.Tables[t].Rows[r]` onde r é o índice da linha.

`DataSet.Tables[t].Rows[r][c]` onde c é o nome ou índice da coluna.

```
DataSet dtteste = conexao.getDataSet("SELECT ID_FUNCIONARIO FROM VW_APONTAMENTO_HORAS WHERE ID_PROJETO="+idProjeto+"GROUP BY ID_FUNCIONARIO");
var count = dtteste.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
List<string> retornos = new List<string>();
foreach(DataRow teste in dtteste.Tables[0].Rows )
{
   retornos.Add(teste[0].ToString());
}
```

**Edit**

Entendendo que você primeiro seleciona os funcionários, e depois em algum momento vai selecionar somente os 'apontamento_horas' para aquele funcionário, deveria ser algo desse tipo o seu `Select`

```
  SELECT 
      ID_APONTAMENTO_HORAS, 
      Projeto,
      Ativ,
      Local,
      [Dt Inic],
      [Dt Fim] 
  FROM VW_APONTAMENTO_HORAS 
  WHERE ID_PROJETO = " + idProjeto +" AND
  ID_FUNCIONARIO= "+ retornos[0] +";";
```

Voltemos ao seu `foreach` se você precisa de uma tabela para cada id_funcionário, faça assim:

```
DataSet dtteste = conexao.getDataSet("SELECT ID_FUNCIONARIO FROM VW_APONTAMENTO_HORAS WHERE ID_PROJETO="+idProjeto+"GROUP BY ID_FUNCIONARIO");
var count = dtteste.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
string SqlApontamentos = "";

foreach(DataRow teste in dtteste.Tables[0].Rows )
{
   SqlApontamentos += @"SELECT 
      ID_APONTAMENTO_HORAS, 
      Projeto,
      Ativ,
      Local,
      [Dt Inic],
      [Dt Fim] 
  FROM VW_APONTAMENTO_HORAS 
  WHERE ID_PROJETO = " + idProjeto +" AND
  ID_FUNCIONARIO= "+ teste[0].ToString() +"; ";

}


DataSet dsApontamentos = conexao.getDataSet(SqlApontamentos);
```

E então no seu DataSet você terá `n` tabelas onde:

`dsApontamentos.Tables[0]` é a primeira, `dsApontamentos.Tables[1]` a segunda... etc

Comment: mais nesse caso onde fica armazenado meus resultados , me pareceu muito mais simples mais ainda n entendi com clareza , sou novo nessa area , mais agradeço a ajuda Rovan!!

Comment: ficou armazenado no retorno agora acho que entendi , muito obrigadooo

Comment: todos os valores estão dentro da `List<string> retornos`. O ideal é saber qual a necessidade para então saber qual recurso utilizar. por hora, recomendo a leitura: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3676/listt-trabalhando-com-listas-genericas-em-csharp.aspx

Comment: eu gostaria de usar esse resultado com um select , mais acho que tenho primeiro que converter para string o retorno ne?? ficaria algo desse tipo

Comment: var teste1 = retornos.ToString();                                       global.CarregaTabelaApontamentoHoras1(tbApontamentoHoras, "SELECT ID_APONTAMENTO_HORAS, Projeto,Ativ,Local,[Dt Inic],[Dt Fim] FROM VW_APONTAMENTO_HORAS WHERE ID_PROJETO =" + idProjeto +"ID_FUNCIONARIO="+teste1.tostring());

Comment: não faz muito sentido você executar um `SELECT` para com o resultado dele, apenas executar outro. Vou colocar como ficaria o código na resposta. E, `var teste1 = retornos.ToString();` está errado, onde retornos é uma `List<>`

Comment: List<string> retornos = new List<string>();
                foreach (DataRow teste in dtteste.Tables[0].Rows)
                {                
                    retornos.Add(teste[0].ToString()   string teste1 = retornos[i].ToString();                    global.CarregaTabelaApontamentoHoras1(tbApontamentoHoras, "SELECT ID_APONTAMENTO_HORAS, Projeto,Ativ,Local,[Dt Inic],[Dt Fim] FROM VW_APONTAMENTO_HORAS WHERE ID_PROJETO =" + idProjeto+"AND ID_FUNCIONARIO="+teste1);

                    i = i + 1;
                }

Comment: acabei fazendo desta forma , mais realmente  não atende bem o que eu necessito , era pra cada resultado eu carregar uma tabela  de apontamentos , mais desta formar ele so carrega o ultimo id enviado , eu eu queria fazer com que pra cada resultado ele criace uma tabela difernete

Comment: exatamente isso cara , você me ajudou de mais , Obrigado Rovann!!!!

Comment: por nada, se possível pode avaliar a resposta como +1 também =]

Comment: eu tentei rovann mais fala que membros com pontuação menor que 15 não podem votar , como fiz meu cadastro ontem ainda n possuo esse ranking , mais assim que tiver eu os pontos eu voto beleza e obriado novamente